# CSS Selectors - how to grab all elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Could someone help how to grab all three elements from the DOM (marked it red) with CSS selector ?

With XPath Im already did it, but with CSS unfortunately I have problem. Thanks in advance

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su0Pi.png)

Comment: With the use of   `button[name='nosend']` at the beginning of selector

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will select your buttons, but could possibly select more if you have multiple forms on the page:

```css
input[type="submit"] { ... }

/* Or more specifically */
input[type="submit"][class*="b-compose__"] { ... }
```

In your comment, you say:

> With the use of button[name='nosend'] at the beginning of selector

There are two problems with this request.

1. You are not using buttons, you are using `<input type="submit" ...>`, which get rendered as buttons by the browser.
2. The `[name='nosend']` part would only select the middle button. Each button has a different name. You could select all three by doing this:

```css
input[name='doit'], 
input[name='nosend'], 
input[name='cancel'] { ... }
```